# Android ListView - Refresh and sort?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I am doing this:

```
// Member variable
List<String> items = null;

// in onCreate
items = new ArrayList<String>();

// later on in a Task (onPostExecute)
items.add(NewItem);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

My List is in Alphabetical order.  When I add an item, it simply puts it at the bottom.  Any way to put it in the proper place?

(Yes it will be in proper order the second time you come back to this page, but not on adding it)

Edit:  I am first putting it in order through a SQL script call.

Comment: Are you using content providers? Must you dynamically add the item or can you insert it into the database and then rely on the a content observer to update it?

Comment: I suppose I can add item to the database and call the whole list back.  But that seems like it would waste resources/battery/time.  So I opted to just add item to list, and item to database separately.  Seems like there is a better way?

Comment: What is `items`?  Is it the listview or the source for the adapter?

Comment: Source of adapter.  An ArrayList<String> I believe.  Will add code to question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to research any methods for ArrayList and did not find any. I did find this, however:

```
items.add(NewItem);
Collections.sort(items);
```

Worked perfectly!  I had to import Collections into the project.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion to your answer is that, as and when you add an item on ListView try to set the adapter again on the list at the time of adding item.

this way you get the refreshed data on your ListView.

Comment: Didn't work.  Thanks though.  If you are curious, I found my answer and just posted it.